# DataGridComboBoxColumn is not initialized because objects are different (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

One of the view contains a DataGrid. The DataGrid is a list of materials and each material contain a unit that you can select via a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

The DataGrid and the DataGridComboBoxColumn are bound to two different `ObservableCollection` in my view model, one for materials and one for units. These collections are initialized from a database on startup.

The problem is that when I first load the page after it got initialized, the DataGridComboBoxColumn does not have a selected value.

It is happening because the unit object inside the material object that is shown is not the same object as the one in the units collection initialized from the database.

This is the view code :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10,0" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Matériel" Binding="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="*"/>
                <mah:DataGridNumericUpDownColumn Header="Prix"
                                                 Binding="{Binding Price}"
                                                 StringFormat="C"
                                                 Minimum="0" 
                                                 Width="*"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unité"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Units}}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Unit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                        Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This is the ViewModel code :

```
public MaterialViewModel(ISessionService sessionService, IMaterialRepository materialRepository)
    {
        _materialRepository = materialRepository;

        Materials = sessionService.Materials;
        Materials.CollectionChanged += MaterialsCollectionChanged;
        foreach (var item in Materials)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += MaterialPropertyChanged;
        }

        Units = sessionService.Units;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }
```

Just to be sure, I tried to initialize the units collection with the unit object that is in the material object and it was working as intended.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: For sure it would not work, as you stated unit objects are not the same. You can do it by
Either use IEquatable. or Bind DataGridComboBoxColumn with SelectedValueBinding. 
Second option is more convenient for you.

Comment: Indeed the second option worked for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `UnitName` or `UnitId` property to the `Material` class and bind to this one using the `SelectedValueBinding` property. Don't forget to also set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "Name" or whatever the value property of the `Unit` class is called:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Unité"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Units}}"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding UnitName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                        SelectedValuePath="Name"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        Width="*"/>
```

Comment: Yes ! SelectedValuePath did the trick. Don't need to add a UnitName property to the Material class, just bind it like so : `SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Unit.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"`